# PhantomJS does not work for Cucumber test

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have added javascript in my Rails app to enable the button only when one of the checkboxes has been checked.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $(function () {
    $('.delete-checkbox').change(function() {
      if ($('.delete-checkbox:checked').length) {
        $('#delete-url-btn').removeAttr('disabled');
      } else {
        $('#delete-url-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
    });
  });
})
```

The code definitely works in the browser when I test it. However, it seems like the javascript is not picked up when I am running my cucumber test with poltergeist (phantomjs). I have added the @javascript tag in my cucumber feature and I have also followed all the instructions on the [phantomjs website](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) to include phantomjs. I am wondering what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

please check if adding 'capybara' gem (if you don't have it in Gemfile)
and following code:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, js_errors: false)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

to the features/support/env.rb file helps.

Also please check if you can run phantomjs from command line, ie. "phantomjs --version". If you're on Ubuntu you have to remove Ubuntu phantomjs package (it's broken: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14376), and use the one from http://phantomjs.org/download.html page.